# Get the Records which contains a word (Case insensitive) in Gql?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql, gqlquery

Is it possible to write a single Gql Query for retrieving the record which contains a searching string?

Data store Contains following Records:

```
addax
Crest
Addrest
Drest
Armrest
admix
```

I need to get the Records which contains the word **"Rest"** (Case insensitive)

Comment: @Wooble Nope - this user also wants fulltext.

Comment: Ah, right. Finding "rest" in "Armrest" is going to be... nontrivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full-Text-Search is not supported in AE yet, it's on the [roadmap](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/roadmap.html) so we can look forward to it.

If you are just trying to match single words in a case insensitive way, you could store all your words in a ListProperty, and ensure they are always stored in lowercase. That way you could easily query for them in a case insensitive mannor.

Comment: @chiris This is a running application. So i cant able to make any changes in the Datastore. And i need to add a new module for Searching a products already in the datastore.

Comment: You might want to look at the aetycoon examples of custom properties, specifically the [TransformProperty](https://github.com/Arachnid/aetycoon/blob/master/__init__.py#L157), which you could use to add a second property based on an existing property. You would have to re save each entity but once in place you would have a useable prop for searching against.

Comment: @chiris thanks for your reply. But Even i need to change the Exsisting datastore model is it ? ( Change all existing data to this property in either uppercase or lowercase ).Is it possible to do programmatic ?

Comment: If you just want to change all the current data, look at using the [mapper api in mapreduce](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/) if you need to keep the existing data you can add a Derived/Transform Property to store the lowercased versions.

Comment: Okey. I Added the normalized text(All lowercase) of a of all products. Then Also i need to fetch all the record and Search a word in each the records. Is it  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get some full text search features using [SearchableModel](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/search/__init__.py)